# How to select a group of elements after every nth-element in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to select a group of elements occurring after nth element in CSS? 
For Example: bold first three, skip next three, bold first three and so on...

***0 0 0*** 0 0 0 ***0 0 0*** 0 0 0 ***0 0 0*** 0 0 0 ***0 0 0***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. you cant select occurring groups, but you can select every Nth element.

therefore, you need to select multiples of 6, and style 3 first elements with offsets +1, +2 and +3 from the recurring N as follows:

the following means in simple words: **"every 6 elements, style only the 1st, 2nd and 3rd one"**

```css
p:nth-child(6n+1), 
p:nth-child(6n+2), 
p:nth-child(6n+3) {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
}
p {
    display:inline;
}
```

```html
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
<p>O</p>
```

Comment: Thank you.. Your answer is better and efficient.